# Repository pattern with Laravel 5

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I have created a couple of Repositories classes in *app/Repositories* like **SeriesRepository**, **CommentRepository** etc. My idea doing this is to abstract the database calls, so I can use Eloquent or the query builder or even raw SQL if I wish without having to change queries in thousands of places in the code.

Since I will be releasing this project as Open Source, I decided to add an interface for each repository. This way anyone who might use the project can create their own version of a specific repository and just implement the interface. Is this an overkill? Is this just overengineering? Should I just skip the interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice, it's recommended to code for an interface, specifically for scalable projects. You may be interested in checking the following **Laravel Repository Package** for most of the work already done & abstracted the way you need: https://github.com/rinvex/repository

It's a simple, intuitive, and smart implementation of Active Repository with extremely flexible & granular caching system for Laravel, used to abstract the data layer, making applications more flexible to maintain. The following diagram shows how it works in short:

[image: Here's a diagram of how it works in short]

Comment: This comment explains it perfectly. Thanks a lot for the tip and the great package. I will definitely use it.